# CSharp Android Xamarin SQL ListView

Tags: c#, android, android-listview, xamarin

I'm trying to read the contents from a SQL query and store them into a listView (Android-C#). For whatever reason the listView is only showing the last item. When I debug through the code, I see that it is going through every result, however, I cannot get the adapter to display all the results. Maybe I am doing something wrong with the adapter. Any ideas?

Code:

```
    while (rdr.Read ()) {

                    string[] Text  = new string[] { (rdr[0])+ System.Environment.NewLine} ;
                    ListView mylistview = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.listView1);
                    var myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1 , Text);
                    mylistview.Adapter = myAdapter;
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For whatever reason the listView is only showing the last item.

Because in  `while` every time new `Text` Array is created and pass to `ArrayAdapter` so last is Array data is showing in ListView.

To show all items in `ListView`,create Adapter object outside `while` loop and use `ArrayList` which will grow according to data-size:

```
ArrayList listText = new ArrayList(); 
while (rdr.Read ()) { 
   listText.add((rdr[0])+ System.Environment.NewLine);
}
ListView mylistview = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.listView1);
var myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
                                Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1,listText);
mylistview.Adapter = myAdapter;
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was a dumb mistake. By the way, I had to use var listText = new List<String>(); instead of ArrayList. Thanks again!